# Adding a bath fan to light circuit causes Dim light and Dim Fan

Tags: electrical

I am replacing a bath fan and forgot to note the old circuit

When i add the fan to the light and switch, the light glows very dim and fan moves very slowly.

The wire from light is hot

Light Black -> Switch Black
Switch White -> Fan Black
Fan white -> Back to light White

Any help appreciated, why it goes dim.

Comment: Pictures of how the wires are connected at the light, the fan and the switch will help.  Do you have the power cable(from panel) at the light fixture?  Are you controlling the fan and light from the same switch of does the fan have it's own switch?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved please?

Comment: Sanity check: if the switch is on, both are on but underpowered, and the switch is off everything is off? Or some other combination? Or is there another switch involved?

Comment: Also, are you sure the main power source is coming in through the switch box, or could this be a switch loop? Photos of both the way the switch box is wired and the fan and light are wired would be _very_ helpful.

Comment: @keshlam you were correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because you wired the light and fan in **series** instead of **parallel**. Therefore, the fan and the light are sharing the 120 volt supply and each receiving a fraction of the full voltage.

The correct wiring is to connect the three black wires (switched hot, fan hot and light hot) together and the three white wires (supply neutral, fan neutral and light neutral) together.

Comment: Yes this is exactly I am trying to resolve, but the power is coming from the one on the Light.  So when I connected Light Black, Fan Black and Switch Black. AND Light white, Fan White, a switch White . Then Even if the switch is off.. the current goes from light Black to Fan Black to Fan White to Light white .. and they turn ON DIM. Even when switch is OFF. and when switch is ON, then it runs fine. Confused :(

Comment: Let me try it again. It makes sense and I was also doing it, but may be I connected something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had to open the light box to get a better understanding.

The wire with current was for the light. So It was expected to be connected to the switch only. So the switch only controls the light.

Then from the light there was a wire drawn (in parallel) which was going to the top. That was my fan input.

Now both light and fan gets controlled by switch.

It would have been impossible to diagnose it on internet with half information, but a electrician would have looked at it and in 1 glance would have figured it out.

Thanks for looking and helping out